# Adjusting warp arc bend with Adobe Illustrator scripting?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, illustrator-scripting

I'm attempting to write an Illustrator script that will get the length of a text phrase...  Then based on the string length, set the warp arc bend, horizontal distortion, vertical distortion to a new value...

Here is my fake pseudo code:

```
if (textlength = 5)
{
warp_bend = 60%
warp_horizontal = 10%
warp_vertical = 25%
}
```

I have looked through the Javascript scripting 2017 guide, and I do not see any variables for these warp values.  Am I missing something, or is this not possible?

Any help is much appreciated.

Wyatt

Answer (score 1):

No you can not do this via the javascript API.

**Late addition**: There is a wholy undocumented feature that can in fact do this in the scripting API. Its a bit tricky it involves reading a saved illustrator file in a text editor and a bit of guesswork

Comment: Do you happen to know if this is something could be done using the SDK or any other 3rd party plugin?

Comment: @WyattJackson you can do it in the C++ SDK if you can afford to learn how to use it. On the other hand you can just add spaces to a set wrap